# Heterogeneous maps in cpp? Is that possible?

Tags: c++

Heterogeneous maps in cpp using only standard libs, no boost? Is it possible? If yes how can I do that?

Like, both the keys and data can be any type (I know in cpp they aren't called like that but ok).

Basically I just need help for a heterogeneous map class

Comment: You can use `std::any` for the data.  The *key* has some requirements that cannot be fulfilled by a `std::any`.

Comment: Umm I was just asking for help on an heterogeneous map class

Comment: I also tried a
```#include <unordered_map>
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> hi;```, didnt work
Does the `any` need more template args?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Failed to compile? (If so, what error message?) Compiled but didn't do what you wanted to? (Give some details about what you wanted it to do and what it did instead.)

Comment: error: no member named 'any' in namespace 'std'
I think its probably that the compiler im using is outdated

Comment: Actually `std::any` needs C++17. That might be the issue here.